# Single word for copy paste errors

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, vocabulary, dictionaries

Is there a single word for copy paste errors? Just like "typo"

Comment: Why have you limited yourself to a single word? Where will you use it?

Comment: Other than a flub or gaffe? Not really. Transposition? Transposing? But I would just call it a typo, flub, gaffe, jumble/jumbling.

Comment: Can you include a sample sentence, showing the context for how the word would be used? This will give people a better sense of what you're looking for. It's also technically required for single-word-requests, and without one there's a danger that your question might be closed.

Comment: As a suggestion: `copy-typo`?

Answer (score 4):

If you can stomach two words, I think a good wording is a **replication error**.

Otherwise, an uncommon word (used in scientific settings) is **misreplication**.

Comment: Even in a scientific setting I think misreplication is rarer than replication error, but it is used — see [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=misreplication%2Creplication+error&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmisreplication%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creplication%20error%3B%2Cc0) so if the OP really wants a single word, you gave him one.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a slang expression I recently encountered for an instance of copying and pasting:

[**copypasta**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copypasta)

For which Wiktionary gives both that and a second meaning:

> **copypasta** (countable and uncountable, plural copypastas)
>
> 1. (Internet, slang) A block of text which has been copied and pasted
>      from somewhere else.
> 2. (Internet, slang) An error in a
>      software application caused by the copy-and-paste of erroneous code.

If you wait long enough (or care to start a trend), the meanings will probably fuse to give you what you want.

Remember, you read it here first.

Comment: copypasta really does refer to newbs copying code that they don't understand into their programs and causing havoc as a result.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 — Yes, that would be Wiktionary's second definition. However I think the poster was referring to doing the same with a text document. I'm pretty sure that if the term spreads outside of IT it will be used in the same way.

Comment: There was a long discussion and essay I did on copypasta recently. I don't think this is what the OP was asking. And @David just an FYI it has spread outside IT. I'm a 30 years veteran of computer science myself. I recently did an essay here on ESS for the origin of copypasta. It's not the same meaning the OP was asking about. No offense intended at all. Just being informative.

Comment: For a thorough discussion on what "copypasta" means, take a look at [Josh's question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399805/origin-and-usage-of-copypasta).

Comment: @Kace36 and RaceYouAnytime — thanks guys. I am on the periphery of IT and hadn't met the term, and think I actually met it on this list in a discussion of answers with dictionary definitions (copypastas) and not much else. And I admit I was trying to be clever, so I deserve to be taken down a peg.